# Microsoft Sync Framework - Sync SQL to/from a hard drive

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a C# application that uses Microsoft Sync Framework to sync an SQL Server database from the server to the client across the internet.
I need to add a new feature, to allow clients to occasionally sync while offline via a portable hard drive.

This would mean that sometimes the client would sync over the internet with the server, and sometimes the client would instead grab data from a portable hard drive.

Does the sync framework offer a method for exporting the server database to a file, and then syncing that file to a client (or something similar)?

I'm having trouble finding any solid documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to sync from portable hard drive, have a look at generating a SQL Ce snapshot (via GenerateSnapshot), send the SQL CE db via portable media, have your app sync the SQL CE snapshot to your local database.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm taking a look at SQL CE just now. Alternatively, I may use the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard to create a package of data, and then just drop the data on the client, and import the package (assuming that the data in the package on the hard drive is newer than the data on the client).

Comment: if you're doing bidirectional sync, just be wary that changes you drop in the client that gets to the client database is not detected as changes to be uploaded to the server.